# How to check if all arguments in method are of specific type?

Tags: java, types, instanceof

I have a method which takes a variable amount of arguments:

```
public void test(Object[] ... args) {}
```

How can I check if **all** arguments are double[]?

Comment: You want to check if all the arguments passed are doubles? Or of type double array?

Comment: have you tried to pass a double[] value to your function?

Comment: an interesting spin on an XY Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop and make sure each Object[] is a Double[]. Note you cannot use primitive double here as that is not an Object.

```
boolean allDoubleArr = true;
for(Object[] o : args) {
    if(!(o instanceof Double[])) {
        allDoubleArr = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DalaiLlama it's a Double[] on purpose since as the question is currently written the method gets a varargs of Object[] so I'm looping through each array.

Comment: double[] is an object. double is not an object.

Comment: @Samuel If you read my answer I made a note of that.

Comment: I'm saying you should change your answer to `instanceof double[]`

Comment: @Samuel That still will not work as the types are not compatible. The following is not allowed to see if it makes it clearer. `Object[] doubles = new double[1]`.

Comment: See my edit for what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the arguments and check:

```
if (obj instanceof Double)
```

Object[] means array can hold double, as well as integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the compiler static type check it by changing your method's signature to this:

```
public void test(Double[] ... args) {}
```

Now the java compiler will enforce it so that `test()` can only be called with `Double[]` parameters.

If you really need to make it a dynamic type check then I vote for @George Mulligan's answer.